# CSS animation visibility issue

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to do some CSS animations, but I just encountered a problem. I want a div to fade in with a delay. So the div shouldn't show until the animation starts.

Here is what I made so far: http://jsfiddle.net/qJfZN/1/

As I said I want the text not to show until the animation fades it in and then I would like the text to be visible after the animation is done.

Anyone has a clue on how I should make this work?

TIA!

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill your animation.

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animatino-fill-mode: both;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qJfZN/3/)